# php 7 does not trigger errors on my local machine

Tags: php

I've installed php 7 on my debian local machine with apache2, when there is an error on a php file it doesn't show up, for example if I echo a variable that I don't declare :

```
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

will output nothing (no error)

my php.ini errors lines looks like this :

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

; html_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: On

; log_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
```

Comment: Did you check to see if error reporting is actually turned on?

Comment: @JohnConde I've updated the question

Comment: Those are not your actual settings. They're instructions in the ini file. Show the actual settings in your ini file

Comment: Without uncommenting it, the default value should stand.

Also, not that it changes anything, but `x` in that case is a constant. `$x` is a variable.

Comment: @JohnConde what do you mean by actual settings in my ini file? sorry I come from a ruby background

Comment: Do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11936959/584490

Comment: Thank you guys I got it to work buy switching display_errors from Off to ON on my php.ini